# How to calculate ajax data that is added to html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have search everywhere and cant seem to find anything on this,
i have an ajax that send data to my php file that then get data from database and is presented in a a div

ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#addForm").on('submit', function (e) {
            // widthMeas and Drop Meas are just the selection of cm/in/m ect

            let Width = document.getElementById('blindWidth').value;
            let widthMeas = document.getElementById('widthMeas').value;

            let height = document.getElementById('height').value;
            let dropMeas = document.getElementById('dropMeas').value;

            let Type = document.getElementById('Type').value

            let quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value

            $.ajax({
                url:"converter.php",
                method: "post",
                data:{
                    Width: Width,
                    widthMeas: widthMeas,
                    Drop: Drop,
                    dropMeas: dropMeas,
                    Type: Type,
                    quantity: quantity
                },
           success:function (data) {
           console.log(data);
           $('#quote').append(data);
           $('#addBlindForm')[0].reset();
           $('#quoteModal').modal('hide');
           $('#quoteContainer').show();
          }
      });
});
```

php file

```
$output .= "
             <tr>
                <td>".$InputWidth."".$widthMeas." x ".$InputDrop."".$dropMeas." </td>
                <td>".$Type."</td>
                <td>".$quantity."</td>
                <td>£ ".$price."</td>
             </tr><br>
                         ";
            echo $output;
            break;
```

i am wanting to know how can i add all of the totals in real time after each new item is added to the 'quote div' it should display

width height type quantity price 
1cm x 1cm  plank    12      44

total 44.00

Comment: what is the formula you are using to get 44.00 .? I need the formula so I can create a script to answer your problem .

Comment: Hi thanks i'm just using the price of the item x the quantity which gives me the total of 44  so item cost 3.6 * 12 = 44

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand  : 3.6*12 = 44 ??

Comment: Keep it in ajax response, see what if your call fails and you updated it in real time before ajax get executed. You can get response as json and create HTML in success then append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the answers here and it lead me to an easier way of doing it I used this solution which allows me to calculate each new element that is added into the div.

```
 $('.calculate').click(function () {
       let total = 0;
       $(".price").each(function () {
          total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
       });

      $('.quote').html(total);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<head>
    <title>Vote</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        Width :
        <input type="number" name="" id="blindWidth">
        <br> Height :
        <input type="number" name="" id="height">
        <br> Type :
        <input type="text" name="" id="Type">
        <br> Quantity :
        <input type="number" name="" id="quantity">
        <br>
        <div id="priceTag">Fill in the inputs above</div>
        <div id="dimensions"></div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calcPrice(quantityValue) {
            quantityValue = quantityValue || 0;
            let basePrice = 12;
            totalPrice = 12 * quantityValue;

            if (totalPrice > 0) {
                document.getElementById('priceTag').innerText = `Price : ${totalPrice}`;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('priceTag').innerText = ``;
            }
        }

        function calcDimensions(heightValue, widthValue) {
            let dimensions = heightValue * widthValue;
            if (dimensions > 0) {
                document.getElementById('dimensions').innerText = `Dimensions : ${dimensions}`;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('dimensions').innerText = ``;
            }
        }
        let width = document.getElementById('blindWidth');
        let height = document.getElementById('height');
        let quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');

        width.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
         //   console.log('typing on width');
            let widthValue = width.value || 0;
            let heightValue = height.value || 0;
            let quantityValue = quantity.value || 0;

            calcDimensions(widthValue, heightValue);
            calcPrice(quantityValue);

        })

        height.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
           // console.log('typing on height');
            let widthValue = width.value || 0;
            let heightValue = height.value || 0;
            let quantityValue = quantity.value || 0;

            calcDimensions(widthValue, heightValue);
            calcPrice(quantityValue);

        })

        quantity.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
           // console.log('typing on quantity');
            let widthValue = width.value || 0;
            let heightValue = height.value || 0;
            let quantityValue = quantity.value || 0;

            calcDimensions(widthValue, heightValue);
            calcPrice(quantityValue);

        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

To have realtime calculations , use JavaScript eventlisteners .

To read more about eventlisteners , see this [article](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp)

Here is the HTML code , click on RUN SNIPPET to see how it works.

Thank you .

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="pt-br">
            <meta charset="utf-8" />

            <head>
                <title>Vote</title>

            </head>

            <body>
                <div>
                    Width :
                    <input type="number" name="" id="blindWidth">
                    <br> Height :
                    <input type="number" name="" id="height">
                    <br> Type :
                    <input type="text" name="" id="Type">
                    <br> Quantity :
                    <input type="number" name="" id="quantity">
                    <br>
                    <div id="priceTag">Fill in the inputs above</div>
                    <div id="dimensions"></div>

                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function calcPrice(quantityValue) {
                        quantityValue = quantityValue || 0;
                        let basePrice = 12;
                        totalPrice = 12 * quantityValue;

                        if (totalPrice > 0) {
                            document.getElementById('priceTag').innerText = `Price : ${totalPrice}`;
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById('priceTag').innerText = ``;
                        }
                    }

                    function calcDimensions(heightValue, widthValue) {
                        let dimensions = heightValue * widthValue;
                        if (dimensions > 0) {
                            document.getElementById('dimensions').innerText = `Dimensions : ${dimensions}`;
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById('dimensions').innerText = ``;
                        }
                    }
                    let width = document.getElementById('blindWidth');
                    let height = document.getElementById('height');
                    let quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');

                    width.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
                        console.log('typing on width');
                        let widthValue = width.value || 0;
                        let heightValue = height.value || 0;
                        let quantityValue = quantity.value || 0;

                        calcDimensions(widthValue, heightValue);
                        calcPrice(quantityValue);

                    })

                    height.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
                        console.log('typing on height');
                        let widthValue = width.value || 0;
                        let heightValue = height.value || 0;
                        let quantityValue = quantity.value || 0;

                        calcDimensions(widthValue, heightValue);
                        calcPrice(quantityValue);

                    })

                    quantity.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
                        console.log('typing on quantity');
                        let widthValue = width.value || 0;
                        let heightValue = height.value || 0;
                        let quantityValue = quantity.value || 0;

                        calcDimensions(widthValue, heightValue);
                        calcPrice(quantityValue);

                    })
                </script>
            </body>

            </html>
```